# MAPI call without blocking application

Tags: c#, multithreading, mapi

My application is sending E-Mails via a MAPI call:

```
[DllImport("MAPI32.DLL")]
static extern int MAPISendMail(IntPtr sess, IntPtr hwnd, MapiMessage message, int flg, int rsv);
```

and somewhere else:

```
m_lastError = MAPISendMail(new IntPtr(0), new IntPtr(0), msg, how, 0);
```

This works well except for one problem: The outlook window will completely block the application.
This seems to be the intended behavior but I would like to not have it behave this way. Any ideas?

I tried calling `MAPI` from a background thread, but it seems that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just the way Simple MAPI works - use OOM instead (`Application.CreateItem` / `MailItem.Display(false)`).

Comment: that will only work for Outlook, though. I refuse to believe there is no workaround for MAPI.

Comment: Outlook *is* MAPI. At least by the market share on Windows. Use OOM for Outlook and Simple MAPI for other clients.